# Error running geotools tutorial for CSV2SHP?

Tags: shapefile, geotools, csv

Although I run [this tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/feature/csv2shp.html) I always get following error message:

> Nov 22, 2011 5:10:50 PM
>   org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedPostgreSQLEpsgFactory
>   isAvailable
>       WARNING: Unavailable authority factory: European Petroleum Survey Group
>       org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException: Failed to connect to the EPSG database.
>         at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:420)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.getBackingStore(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:131)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:233)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:117)
>         at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAvailable(FactoryRegistry.java:665)
>         at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAcceptable(FactoryRegistry.java:499)
>         at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry$1.filter(FactoryRegistry.java:190)
>         at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.advance(ServiceRegistry.java:810)
>         at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
>         at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.getServiceProviders(ServiceRegistry.java:508)
>         at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProviders(FactoryRegistry.java:195)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:176)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:451)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.getBackingFactory(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:88)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:69)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.getAuthorityFactory(CRS.java:229)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:467)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:395)
>         at org.geotools.data.DataUtilities.createAttribute(DataUtilities.java:2172)
>         at org.geotools.data.DataUtilities.createType(DataUtilities.java:1752)
>         at org.geotools.data.DataUtilities.createType(DataUtilities.java:1702)
>         at org.geotools.tutorial.Csv2Shape.main(Csv2Shape.java:61)
>       Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "Geotools"
>         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:291)
>         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
>         at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
>         at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
>         at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
>         at org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3Connection.(Jdbc3Connection.java:24)
>         at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
>         at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
>         at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
>         at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
>         at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:87)
>         at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:70)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.DirectEpsgFactory.getConnection(DirectEpsgFactory.java:3172)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:415)
>         ... 21 more
>
> Nov 22, 2011 5:10:52 PM 
>    org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedPostgreSQLEpsgFactory
>   isAvailable
>       WARNING: Unavailable authority factory: European Petroleum Survey Group
>       org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException: Failed to connect to the EPSG database.
>         at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:420)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.getBackingStore(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:131)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:233)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:117)
>         at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAvailable(FactoryRegistry.java:665)
>         at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAcceptable(FactoryRegistry.java:499)
>         at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceImplementation(FactoryRegistry.java:435)
>         at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProvider(FactoryRegistry.java:363)
>         at org.geotools.factory.FactoryCreator.getServiceProvider(FactoryCreator.java:143)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getAuthorityFactory(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:216)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactory(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:436)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.LongitudeFirstFactory.createBackingStore(LongitudeFirstFactory.java:189)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.getBackingStore(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:131)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:233)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:117)
>         at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAvailable(FactoryRegistry.java:665)
>         at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAcceptable(FactoryRegistry.java:499)
>         at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry$1.filter(FactoryRegistry.java:190)
>         at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.advance(ServiceRegistry.java:810)
>         at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.next(ServiceRegistry.java:828)
>         at org.geotools.resources.LazySet.addNext(LazySet.java:70)
>         at org.geotools.resources.LazySet.get(LazySet.java:120)
>         at org.geotools.resources.LazySet$Iter.next(LazySet.java:139)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ManyAuthoritiesFactory.(ManyAuthoritiesFactory.java:118)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.getBackingFactory(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:116)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:69)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.getAuthorityFactory(CRS.java:229)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:467)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:395)
>         at org.geotools.data.DataUtilities.createAttribute(DataUtilities.java:2172)
>         at org.geotools.data.DataUtilities.createType(DataUtilities.java:1752)
>         at org.geotools.data.DataUtilities.createType(DataUtilities.java:1702)
>         at org.geotools.tutorial.Csv2Shape.main(Csv2Shape.java:61)
>       Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "Geotools"
>         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:291)
>         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
>         at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
>         at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
>         at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
>         at org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3Connection.(Jdbc3Connection.java:24)
>         at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
>         at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
>         at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
>         at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
>         at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:87)
>         at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:70)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.DirectEpsgFactory.getConnection(DirectEpsgFactory.java:3172)
>         at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:415)
>         ... 32 more
>
> Nov 22, 2011 5:10:58 PM org.geotools.referencing.factory.PropertyAuthorityFactory 
>       WARNING: Axis elements found in a wkt definition, the force longitude first axis order hint might not be respected:
>       PROJCS["Google Projection",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563,
>   AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",
>   0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295],AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST],AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Popular
>   Visualisation Pseudo Mercator",
>   AUTHORITY["EPSG","1024"]],PARAMETER["semi_minor",
>   6378137.0],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0],PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0],PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0],PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0],PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0],UNIT["m", 1.0]]

What might be the cause that application throws this error I have not used any database here?

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried the tutorial, but it looks like it can't find the projection codes database which it needs to map EPSG codes to projection definitions.

The tutorial mentions pulling in some dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
    <version>${geotools.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
    <version>${geotools.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The second one looks like the culprit, and the documentation says it'll download the driver and so on. I would have thought, though it doesn't say explicitly, that it also gets the database and puts it somewhere it can find it, so it may be worth checking your installation of GeoTools to make sure everything is where it should be.